# How to access the service in separate process while using queue in NestJs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs

I was implementing queues using NestJs and wanted to use a separate process functionality.
https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/queues#separate-processes

So in this case, I wanted to call a function which is being used in one of my services.But I am not sure how I can do this since as per the documentation:

> Please note that because your function is being executed in a forked
> process, Dependency Injection (and IoC container) won't be available.
> That means that your processor function will need to contain (or
> create) all instances of external dependencies it needs.

How do I access my service function by accessing the external dependancy?
This is my code

```
import { Job } from 'bull'; 
import { Logger } from '@nestjs/common'; 
import { ModuleRef } from '@nestjs/core';

export default function (job: Job) {
   const options = JSON.parse(job?.data['text']);  
   Logger.verbose(options.region); 
}
```